# Need help to pass information between content script and web_accessible_resources(js file)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script with some data read form the content script 
//Manifest file

```
   {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Random App",
  "description": "This App will do random stuff",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["InjectScript.js"],

  "permissions": ["tabs", "background", "storage","https://www.youtube.com/*" ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "This is just a random app",
    "default_icon": "hello.png"
  }     
}
```

//Content.js My requirement is to send firstParamTobeSent and secondParamTobeSent to InjectScript

```
var firstParamTobeSent = "Stackoverflow";
var secondParamTobeSent = "Stackoverflow2";

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('InjectScript.js');
alert("got the URL on InjectScript");

s.onload = function() {

    alert("1." + firstParamTobeSent + "----" + secondParamTobeSent);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
window.postMessage("YourName_expectedMessage");  //If I comment this line alert 1 and 2 start working.
alert("2." + firstParamTobeSent + "----" + secondParamTobeSent);
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

//InjectScript.js

```
   window.addEventListener("message", function(request) { 
    alert("Reaching here = " + request.data + "ORGIN = " + request.origin);
    if (request.data == "YourName_expectedMessage") //note that there are likely many script on the page or it's child frames that also send messages to this page, so you better name
    { 
        alert("It works");
    } 
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally used

```
s.onload = function() {

var evt=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
        evt.initCustomEvent("yourCustomEvent", true, true, { 'Data1' : 'Value1' , 'Data2' : 'Value2' });
        document.dispatchEvent(evt);
...//Ur code
}

//Injected.js
document.addEventListener('yourCustomEvent', function (e)
{ 
  d1= e.detail.Data1;
  d2 = e.detail.Data2;
  alert("received d1= " + d1 + "d2 = " + d2);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For messaging from content script to page script you can use this code:

`window.postMessage("YourName_expectedMessage", "*")`.

On the page script (WebAccessibleResources.js) you should use

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(request) { 

    if (request.data == "YourName_expectedMessage") //note that there are likely many script on the page or it's child frames that also send messages to this page, so you better name your message so that is unique in the entire world.
    { 
        ... 
    } 

}, true);
```

Alternatively, you can create tags on the page and store necessary data in the attributes of these tags, so that the other end can read them.

Comment: By tags you mean I should use local storage ?

Comment: @DeepikaAnand What is not working? Please help me to help you! Do you think I just wrote unintelligible stuff hoping it randomly works? It should work, else I would not have written it. Are you asking for next random code now? ;) By tags I mean web page HTML tags.

Comment: Oh no I didn't mean that you wrote some random stuff. Of course it must have worked for you sometime. I will edit the code of the question to explain the issue. Can you please give me an example of HTML tags or link on which I can read further about it. This is something new to me.

Comment: @DeepikaAnand Hi Deepika. Now that is more concrete :) Based on Your code I also edited my answer. I think the second argument to `postMessage` may be mandatory, I missed it before. I apologise for confusion. Note also that I am not sure about the `s.onload` part in your code. As far as I have experimented, then you can simply write `s.parentNode.removeChild(s);` directly after inserting the node, since the inserted script node will be executed before the injector continues. But if your code works there (regarding the `onload`) then I think your version is better, and then keep it as it is!